# Input from a file (using command line) and then normal stdin keyboard input (C)

Tags: c

Is there a possible way to use a *.txt file as an input for certain things using command below -

```
a.out<input.txt
```

And then use normal inputs from the user?

Comment: In MSVC there are functions in `conio.h` which obtain input (and write ouput) directly from (to) the console, but they are non-standard. Or you could open the file in the program and read it directly.

Comment: What are "normal" inputs?  You get one standard input stream.  If you choose to attach a regular file to that input stream, then your program will read from that.  You might use `ncurses` to read from a tty (stop thinking of the terminal as "stdin"; they are different things).  Or you might try `cat input.txt - | a.out` or `{ cat input.txt; cat /dev/tty; } | a.out` or try opening `/dev/tty` directly inside your program.  You have many options.  First, provide a precise meaning of "normal inputs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use:

```
$ ./a.out input.txt     # No shell I/O redirection
```

You then open (each of) the command line argument(s) for reading, read it, and close it.  When you're done, you can read from `stdin` until EOF.

On a Unix-like system, you could also support:

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt   # Shell I/O redirection
```

and read from standard input to EOF, and then do one of a number of things to read from the keyboard:

- Open `/dev/tty` and read from that.
- Open `/dev/tty` and duplicate it to `stdin` (`freopen()`).

There are some less kosher possibilities too; one is to use the standard output or standard error file descriptor as an input file descriptor, using `fdopen()`.  This will often work if the streams are connected to a terminal.  The classic way to start a shell is to open `/dev/tty` for reading and writing, and then duplicate the read/write descriptor to standard input, output and error.  If the output is piped to another program, or redirected to a file, this won't work, of course.  You could use `isatty()` to check whether the file descriptors are associated with a terminal or not.

There are probably other ways to do it too — different ones if you're on Windows.

Personally, I'd go with the 'read command line arguments as files, then read standard input' option, but YMMV.